# How do i add some space between three buttons and place in the centre of the screen CSS

Tags: css, flexbox, display

Hi so im trying to make a Rock Paper Scissors game however the three buttons are too close together so i need to add some spacing. Also i want the buttons in the centre of the screen but not affect the header.

```
body {
    background-color: black;
    display: block;
    justify-content: center;
    align-self: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    font-family: consolas;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

header {
    text-align: center;
}

.buttons {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 10px;
}

#btn {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: none;
    background-color: darkgray;
    -webkit-box-reflect: below 10px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(50%, transparent), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)));
}
```

Comment: #btn { width: calc( 150px - 15px); } else you can set width for buttons container to 450px and justify-content:space-between and btn to width: calc( 33.3333% - 15px)

Comment: In order to solve your problem, please provide your html code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not add more spacing by increasing the margin?:

```
.buttons {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

Or if you only want horizontal spacing:

```
.buttons {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```